# What's the difference of the query with IN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

I have two MySQL tables, `Post`, and `Account`.

I use `NodeJS` for my backend **API**, and it generates the following `SQL` statement:

```
select `p`.`id` as `post_id`
from `Post` as `p` 
left join `Account` as `a` 
    on `a`.`id` = `p`.`author` 
where `p`.`id` in ('9', '10', '76', '77', 123) 
order by `p`.`id` asc
```

the code works, the problem it's **SLOW**! I tried to use `EXPLAIN` to check what happened, it doesn't use **INDEX**:

[image: explaing0]

But, then I notice that the **IN** clause is mixed with number and string, so I change `123` to `'123'` and **EXPLAIN** again, it uses **INDEX** now:

[image: explaing1]

So, my question is what happens when numbers and varchars are mixed inside an **IN**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ricky, is the performance of the query improved if you use (9, 10, 76, 77, 123)? How does performance change if you use ('9', '10', '76', '77', '123')?

Comment: No pictures thanks. Just paste the text directly

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam, that thread is useful and related, but does not answer the question of the op, since it deals with the fact that the results might be inconsistent since different comparison operators are used (MySQL bug if you ask me), however, that does not explain the performance issue here. It is probable that varchar comparisons are done, but I do not know that for sure and the other question does not imply it.

Comment: Data type for p.id column?

Comment: Performance issue get resolved at above when same data type will be used

Comment: use numbers is faster than strings @LajosArpad

Comment: sorry for that, I'm using a GUI software, so I can't copy the result as text @Strawberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the MySQL-Documentation [How MySQL uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html) you will note the following statement:

> Comparison of dissimilar columns (comparing a string column to a
>   temporal or numeric column, for example) may prevent use of indexes if
>   values cannot be compared directly without conversion. For a given
>   value such as 1 in the numeric column, it might compare equal to any
>   number of values in the string column such as '1', ' 1', '00001', or
>   '01.e1'. This rules out use of any indexes for the string column.

So if you mix up data types in your `IN`-Statement it coould prevent the usage of an index.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select `p`.`id` as `post_id`
from `Post` as `p` left join
     `Account` as `a` 
     on `a`.`id` = `p`.`author` 
where `p`.`id` in ('9', '10', '76', '77', 123) 
order by `p`.`id` asc;
```

Should take advantage of an index on `Post(id)` for the `where` clause.  It might or might not be able to use the index for the `order by`.

Two reasons come to mind as to why an index on `Post(id)` would not be used.  The first is type conversion.  The `in` list consists of strings.  My guess is that `id` is an integer.  Sometimes, type conversions can preclude the use of an index.  You can check if this is the case by changing the logic to:

```
where p.id in (9, 10, 76, 77, 123)
```

The second reason is simply that the tables are so small.  MySQL does take cardinality into account when choosing the execution plan.  For small tables, a full-table scan can be more efficient than an index.  In this case, MySQL should always use a covering index.  If you want to test this possibility, create an index on `Posts(id, author)`.  This covers the query and should be preferred by the optimizer.